# Cannot search emails in OST when Exchange is using dial-tone database

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2010

We are temporarily using a dial-tone database in Exchange 2003. One user is viewing their "old data" (their local OST).

When they attempt to search for a mail item within that OST in Outlook 2010, they get no results, even when they know there are emails that match the search criteria. I've attempted this with the normal folder search and "Advanced Find" in the search menu, both showing no results.

How can I resolve this, so they can search within their old OST?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is related to indexing, causing the search to return no results. Please review this MS link to see if you can enable the indexing for the OST file

[Outlook search returns No matches found](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2769651)

It has information on how to review the index, and how these are build